# Можно ли так расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Прежде,  чем  ответить  на  поставленный  вопрос  необходимо  уточнить,  что  важнее  для  ТПА —  герметизация  или  герметичность,  поэтому  обратимся  к  понятиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем ответить на поставленный вопрос, необходимо уточнить, что важнее для ТПА — герметизация или герметичность, поэтому обратимся к понятиям.

Прежде чем- составной союз, в начале придаточного предложения не расчленяется. Вы не обозначили конец придаточного. Остальное верно.